# Linux kernel with include

Tags: module, linux-kernel, makefile

I writing the following for kernel module building:

```
KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
obj-m=hello.o
PWD= $(shell pwd)
default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

It's work fine. I'm trying to rewrite this make-file using `include` directive:

```
KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
obj-m=hello.o
PWD= $(shell pwd)
SUBDIRS=$(PWD)
include $(KDIR)/Makefile
```

But the following errors are caused:

```
/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build/Makefile:323: /home/toker/bundocode/gettingstart/kernel/superhello/scripts/Kbuild.include: No such file or directory
/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build/Makefile:573: /home/toker/bundocode/gettingstart/kernel/superhello/arch/x86/Makefile: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/toker/bundocode/gettingstart/kernel/superhello/scripts/gcc-goto.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: because that's NOT how you build modules.  The kernel source makefile is a complex beast you don't use it the way you think

Answer (score 0):

Kernel makefiles are intended to be included from a parent makefile which contains all of the necessary information to build and link - including the information you were looking to get from your include.  This allows the main kbuild process to decide which compiler, which architecture, etc it is building for, based on what the user configures via menuconfig.  Getting these definitions from an out-of-tree makefile would undermine that (and would reduce portability of code).

You should read this for information: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

John